# Посчитать сумму всех элементов двумерного массива используя Parallel Stream и Multithreading Java

Tags: java, массивы, многопоточность, concurrency, parallelstream

Есть метод, который считает сумму всех элементов двумерного массива:

```
int sum2DArray(int[][] array) {
  int sum = 0;
  for (int[] ints : array) {
      for (int number : ints) {
          sum += number;
      }
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Как можно переписать данный метод и увеличить производительность, чтобы посчитать сумму всех элементов двумерного массива, используя **Parallel Stream** и **Multithreading**?

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их **самостоятельно** перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Преобразование в параллельный поток достаточно тривиально при помощи метода [`BaseStream::parallel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/BaseStream.html#parallel--):

```java
public static int sum2DArray(int[][] arr) {
    return Arrays.stream(arr)          // Stream<int[]> - sequential
        .parallel();                   // Stream<int[]> - parallel
        .flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream)  // IntStream - parallel
        .sum();
}
```

По умолчанию параллельные потоки используют [`ForkJoinPool::commonPool`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html#commonPool--).